# Accidentally ran git clean -d -f and need to get back python3.7

Tags: python, django, git

Won't be running that again, but I've managed to salvage most everything except when I try to run `git pull` I get an error (because these files were removed)

```
error: unable to create file /settings/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc (Permission denied)
error: unable to create file /settings/__pycache__/base.cpython-37.pyc (Permission denied)
error: unable to create file /settings/__pycache__/dev.cpython-37.pyc (Permission denied)
error: unable to create file /settings/__pycache__/local.cpython-37.pyc (Permission denied)
error: unable to create file /settings/__pycache__/prod.cpython-37.pyc (Permission denied)
```

Because running `git clean  -d  -f .` removed

```
Removing lib/python3.6/
Removing lib/python3.7/site-packages/allauth/
Removing lib/python3.7/site-packages/autoslug/
Removing lib/python3.7/site-packages/captcha/
Removing lib/python3.7/site-packages/cities_light/
Removing lib/python3.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/
Removing lib/python3.7/site-packages/defusedxml/
Removing lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauthlib/
Removing lib/python3.7/site-packages/openid/
Removing lib/python3.7/site-packages/progressbar/
Removing lib/python3.7/site-packages/python_utils/
Removing lib/python3.7/site-packages/ranged_response/
Removing lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/
Removing lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlparse/
Removing lib/python3.7/site-packages/unidecode/
Removing lib/python3.7/site-packages/whitenoise/__pycache__/
Removing lib/python3.7/site-packages/whitenoise/runserver_nostatic/__pycache__/
Removing lib/python3.7/site-packages/whitenoise/runserver_nostatic/management/__pycache__/
Removing lib/python3.7/site-packages/whitenoise/runserver_nostatic/management/commands/__pycache__/
Removing success.html
Removing profile_pics/13958293_10209401380008125_7702518920572958301_o_2.JPG
warning: failed to remove /settings/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
warning: failed to remove /settings/__pycache__/base.cpython-36.pyc
warning: failed to remove /settings/__pycache__/prod.cpython-36.pyc
warning: failed to remove /settings/__pycache__/local.cpython-36.pyc
Removing /static/
Removing /migrations/.0011_auto_20190217_1023.py.swp
```

I don't want to do any more damage and am unsure of how to proceed. I'm running this Django Python project on Ubuntu 16.04, do I need to re-install `python3.7`?

`ls -lh` returns

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 trillav trillav    0 Mar  6 15:15 all
drwxrwxr-x 3 trillav trillav 4.0K Mar  8 14:03 bin
drwxrwxr-x 2 trillav trillav 4.0K Mar  6 15:15 include
drwxrwxr-x 3 trillav trillav 4.0K Mar 28 12:01 lib
-rw-rw-r-- 1 trillav trillav   59 Mar  6 15:15 pip-selfcheck.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 trillav trillav  312 Mar  6 15:15 README.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 trillav trillav  683 Mar  8 14:03 requirements.txt
drwxrwxr-x 3 trillav trillav 4.0K Mar  6 15:15 src
```

Comment: @BearBrown Any ideas?

Comment: do you have virtual environment setup? and do you have your own requirements.txt for the solution?

Comment: what is your .gitignore file?

Comment: Yes I have a virtualenv set up and I have my own requirements.txt which I have reinstalled

Comment: You should not track `.pyc` files. Add it to gitignore. If you have a requirements.txt or pipfile you need to install all your dependencies again from there. Try git pull with `sudo`

Comment: .gitignore is `*.pyc
*.sqlite3
db.sqlite3
/settings/local` @BearBrown

Comment: i created the empty repo with recommended by github `.gitignore` https://github.com/gitavk/todoremoveit/blob/master/.gitignore try to use it.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal reinstalling requirements.txt says that all requirements are already satisfied

Comment: what is your env path? inside your project?

Comment: Well then maybe it is. Just run `python manage.py runserver` then

Comment: what is result `ls -lh` inside your project?

Comment: I am unable to `git pull` because the error keeps coming up which I have shown above. The results of `ls -ls` are updated in the question.

Comment: Thank you @BearBrown I have updated my .gitignore.

Comment: `env` is outside of my project in the home directory

Comment: settings is located in `project/src/project/project/settings/` and the files are `base.py  dev.py  __init__.py  local.py  prod.py  __pycache__`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190839/discussion-between-bear-brown-and-trilla).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like some files inside your project are not belong to you, you can find it

```
find . \! -user trillav -print
```

so to fix it you can try to change owner by next command

```
sudo chown -R trillav:trillav .
```

Comment: Also running `sudo git pull` solved my problem and recreated the files...many thanks.

Comment: glad to help you!